# Getting caught Button in netbeans

Tags: java, button, netbeans

I build an app for solving a math question and design a button for beginnig calculation.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    SolvingProblem();
}
```

when I press the button, it Getting caught during calculation.

[image]

what is the problem? how can fix it?
Thanks

Comment: Add the logcat error trace.